# Pandas confusion on dtype error when using 'string'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many mixed types.  I am trying to check for isna().any() and if one is found change that NaN to the appropriate blank, e.g. '-' for string and 0 for int.
When I check this a particular date column against string the error says "string" is not understood.  Whilst it works for other columns in the table.  see below for the different and confusing outcomes.

complete_data_df['idh_due_date', ' '].dtype => dtype('<M8[ns]')

complete_data_df['idh_due_date', ' '].dtype == '<M8[ns]' => True

complete_data_df['idh_due_date', ' '].dtype == str => False

complete_data_df['idh_due_date', ' '].dtype == 'string' =>  data type "string" not understood

complete_data_df['Cust_city', ' '].dtype == 'string' =>  True

complete_data_df['Cust_city', ' '].dtype == str => False

The overall goal I am trying to accomplish again is to fill in blanks with the correct type.  I am certain there are better ways to do the below and am open to suggestions here too.

```
for col in complete_data_df.columns:
if complete_data_df[col].isna().any():
    print(col)
    print(complete_data_df[col].dtype)
    if complete_data_df[col].dtype == float:
        complete_data_df[col].fillna(0, inplace = True)
    elif complete_data_df[col].dtype == object:
        complete_data_df[col].fillna('-', inplace = True)
    elif complete_data_df[col].dtype == int:
        complete_data_df[col].fillna(0, inplace = True)
    elif complete_data_df[col].dtype == 'string':
        complete_data_df[col].fillna('-', inplace = True)
    elif complete_data_df[col].dtype == '<M8[ns]':
        complete_data_df[col].fillna(pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900'), inplace = True)
    else:
        print('error********************')
```

[Jupyter notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6cPK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` with a dict mapping:

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [pd.to_datetime('2022-01-20'), np.NaN],
                   'B': [3.3, np.NaN], 'C': ['Hello', np.NaN]})
print(df)

# Output
           A    B      C
0 2022-01-20  3.3  Hello
1        NaT  NaN    NaN
```

```
df = df.fillna(df.dtypes.replace({'datetime64[ns]': pd.to_datetime('1900-1-1'), 
                                  'float64': 0., 'object': '-'}))
print(df)

# Output
           A    B      C
0 2022-01-20  3.3  Hello
1 1900-01-01  0.0      -
```

Comment: When I try this on my dataframe I get error "len() of unszied object"

Comment: Do you have any numpy array in your dataframe?

Comment: I shouldn't but I could.  How would I find that?  Thanks for the help by the way.